# Data pumping in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11gr2

my problem in using remap_data option while importing data.
scenario:

```
 create table test(fname varchar(20), lname varchar(20),fullname varchar(40));
 insert into test values('govind', 'verma','');
```

by mistake I forgot to insert data in full name (I have huge data so I can't perform update operation so I went for data pumping ) I exported data using expdp but while loading back i want to perform a operation using remap_data option in such a way input of that remap function should be fname and lname but wanna modify in

```
fullname=concat(fname,':',lname)
```

for each row. Is it possible ?

Comment: Why don't you just make `fullname` a virtual column, if it's always going to be the concatenation of the other two anyway?

Comment: can u please elaborate it with proper syntax data already in table  ?

Answer (score 1):

If the full name is always the concatenation of the first and last name, rather than try to supply and maintain that manually you could use [a virtual column](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#BABCHBHE) instead:

```
alter table test drop column fullname;
alter table test add fullname generated always as (fname||' '||lname);

select * from test;

FNAME       LNAME       FULLNAME
----------- ----------- ------------------
govind      verma       govind verma
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c41f/1).

You don't need to update existing rows or export/import; the virtual value is generated automatically when queried. Depending on how it will be used you might benefit from adding an index on it like any other column.